# Why is an OPTIONS request sent instead of a PUT in my Angular 2 app?

Tags: javascript, api, angular, cors

I am trying to perform the update function of a model, trying to call the Update method in the API via PUT.

This is my service client:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

[...]

    updateClients(client_id, data){
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

              let body = JSON.stringify(data);

              return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/client/`+client_id, body, headers)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => response.json().data)
                .then(items => items.map((item, idx)  => {
                  return{
                    id: item.id
                  };
                }));
    }
```

But it does not work since the method goes by OPTIONS and not PUT. And in my browser console it comes out: `XMLHttpRequest can not load`http://ip/api/client/5`. Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.`

But, in the API (Laravel 5.3) the PUT method is enabled. I have tried it with POSTMAN and it's works. And in my response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
```

Why does it come via options request and not put? The POST method works in angular 2.

Answer (score 2):

`OPTIONS` is a preflight request automatically sent by the browser in some CORS situations. If the server doesn't respond with the expected CORS headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and others) the browser won't make the `PUT` request at all.

You need to configure the server to respond with the expected headers to be able to use this server directly from Angular (or JS in general)